# When using Tor, will different tabs follow different pathways?

Tags: onion-routing

If I have two tabs open, will tab one route through Alice to get to Bob and will tab two also route through Alice to get to Dave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tor Browser, isolation is performed by the first party domain. So, if tab A is for `bob.com` as the domain and tab B is for `dave.com`, they will use distinct circuits.

However, if tab A and tab B are both for `bob.com` then they will both use the same circuit.

Note that a circuit conists of 3 or more relays, the first relay will stay the same over a long time period, this is your Guard relay (or a Bridge, if you use one). The other relays are subject to change on a circuit to circuit basis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right [here in official docs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort) : you need to specify corresponding flag to SocksPort - *IsolateDestAddr*